# How to add new column to existing table and set it value based on existing column using EF migrations

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

For example have a table with values:

```
Id CarModel
1  Passat
2  Land Cruiser
```

And need to add non nullable column Manufacturer.
Initial values for Manufacturer (for existing records) should be:

```
For CarModel=Passat - VW 
For CarModel=Land Cruiser - Toyota
etc.
```

My migration:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
  migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
  name: "Manufacturer",
  table: "Cars",
  nullable: false);
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No really good way to do that. You need to edit the generated migration manually as follows:

1. Modify the `AddColumn` command to create the column initially with `nullable` set to  `true` (i.e. *optional*).
2. Populate the column using the `Sql` method and raw SQL commands.
3. Add `AlterColumn` command to change the column `nullable` to the intended `false` (i.e. *required*).

Something like this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
        name: "Manufacturer",
        table: "Cars",
        nullable: true);

    migrationBuilder.Sql(
@"UPDATE Cars SET Manufacturer = CASE CarModel
  WHEN 'Passat' THEN 'VW'
  WHEN 'Land Cruiser' THEN 'Toyota'
  ELSE 'Other' END");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
        name: "Manufacturer",
        table: "Cars",
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(string),
        oldNullable: true);
}
```

Comment: So I am not sure why, but if I didn't have oldNullable : true, it was just completely ignored left it nullable and told me everything was great, I do not like that, but this post finally got this working for me, Thanks!