# Default Value on migration with special condition EF Core 6.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, migration, ef-core-6.0

As provided in Docs, you can simply set any kind of default values in EntityConfiguration using [`.HasComputedColumnSql()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations) or `.HasDefaultValue()`, or in Migration script using proper method parameters.
You can even use sql funtions such as `NEWID()` in order to tell sql to generate random uniq string for default values (which acts like `Guid()`.

My problem is:

I'm trying to add a new column to my already existing table which contains important data,
this new column is gonna have random unique value but not GUIDS(as generated in `NEWID()` funtion in T-SQL), something like what `Random.Next(0,10)` provides but unique.

I tried writing C# methods to generate random numbers using `Random.Next(0,10)` inside migrations script and used some extra code to see if I can make it unique or not,
but it seems I am doing it wrong, can't find a proper way of doing so.
Anyone has any ideas how am I supposed to do so?

So to make the problem clear:

> I want to generate Random unique number as default values for new column that I'm adding to my existing table(my table has a huge number of records).

Answer (score 1):

First, I would not use the Random class to generate unique values as you will get repeated data.

There is no out-of-the-box functionality to achieve what you need (that I am aware of), but the following is one way to do it.

- Add your new column with an EF migration and set this to be nullable, initially.
- Run some SQL to loop over each record and populate this new column with incrementing values i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc. I would probably create and call a stored procedure.
- Update the new column so any new records are auto-incremented ensuring you set the start number (9586 in the example) to correct values based on your data

  ALTER TABLE yourTable ALTER yourNewColumn INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (9586, 1)

This post may also be useful - [How to add new column to existing table and set it value based on existing column using EF migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629811/how-to-add-new-column-to-existing-table-and-set-it-value-based-on-existing-colum)

Comment: It is a nice and easy-to-go way to achieve the result using T-SQL after initializing the table or column, but I was looking for more-likely code first way of handling such situation.